# Turn off PIP for calls

Tags: calls, android-10, motorola

On my Motorola One and under Android 10, whenever I exit Call app during an active call, a picture-in-picture mode for this app is enabled:

[image]

This is super-annoying. How can I disable or turn-off this behavior?

I tried the usual way, i.e. by disabling this feature in Picture-in-picture section of Settings. But there is no sign of Call app there.

[image]

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: If you by any chance have "Display over other apps" setting turned on for your phone app, just turn it off...

Comment: @MANI Yes, this is exactly the thing. Care to craft a full-featured answer out of this comment, so I can accept it a bring you some rep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Display over other apps" is the setting you must look for when some app (in the form of bubble in your case) is floating on other app.

PIP and "Display over other apps" are 2 different settings.
Latter is mostly non-obtrusive until user interact with it. PIP in contrast takes up screen space to show something informative. Only common thing is they can be moved anywhere on the screen and can be dismissed by dragging towards bottom of the screen.